# How to identify computer which I have redirected

Tags: session, authentication, dns, webserver

I have the following problem to solve:

I few months ago I startet a website where you can watch youtube videos which aren't available in your country. Everythings works fine but now I want to offer a new method where I route all the requests directly over my server. Therefore I will later use a custom DNS-Server. Right now I use the hosts file for testing but I have really no idea how i can identify the user. I can promp the user user to login on a website but I will that it works systemwide so if he use a youtube downloader for example it have to work there either and not only in the browser where I could use a session system with cookies. I want a solution where the user can identify himself once in a time like a website or something like this but how can my server detect if this is a user which is logged in or if he is not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways that this could be accomplished with varying levels of difficulty.

1. standard proxy server over https. Your service could simply be a proxy server and then every "client" would update their browser to point to your proxy server. You could also simplify this by using a proxy PAC file (proxy auto config).
2. An anonomyzing interface. The end user would not be able to use their standard search tools etc, instead they would have to use a web page much like what google translate does.
3. A browser plugin. There are already firefox plugins which do something similar to this. They change the way that the browser resolves DNS. This may be the best bet for you but would require development work.
4. An actual install utility that you have your users install on their machines which update the dns servers.